# Java - stop Timer during user input (Countdown)

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have implemented a new class, and what I am trying to do is a countdown. This countdown should start before asking for user input. If it ends during the "waiting for user input", then the Timer should "return" a status or something similar to signal that the time is up. Therefore, I will not ask for the input again, but I skip a big part of my program.

Here is what I have:

```
public class Reminder
{
    Timer timer;
    public Reminder(int seconds)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Time's up!");
            timer.cancel();

            // here instead of System.exit(0), I should do something like "return status"
            System.exit(0);
        }
     }
}
```

And where I call it:

```
Reminder rm = new Reminder(seconds);
do
{
    x = Handler.getCoordinates(in, 'x');
    y = Handler.getCoordinates(in, 'y');
    // ... other stuff here             
} while(!result);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry :) What I would like to have is starting a countdown. If time is up and I am still waiting for user input on Handler.getCoordinates(...), then I should stop it, exit the while loop and have a sort of "flag" (time is up)

Comment: your code shows that you are doing that through /results/ - do you have a full code or are these bits that you are thinking up?

Comment: After getting x and y, I add items on a board (matrix [][])... Result is to check if the item has been correctly placed. If not, then I ask again for input. My idea is to stop, let's say after I got x and getting y, when the time is over.

Comment: you can have a boolean in Timer and check that